# Why the code get executed twice?

Tags: c

I am trying to write code for reverse polish notation calculator. Why when I input a number the following code gets executed twice ?

```
int a[50];
int topOfStack = -1;
char c;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    int n = atoi(&c);
    topOfStack += 1;
    a[topOfStack] = n;
    printf("top of stack is %d\n", a[topOfStack]);
    printf("index top of stack is %d\n", topOfStack);   
}


return 0;
```

}

Comment: There is no `else` in your code.

Comment: Why do you think that processing a single character at a time is a good idea?

Comment: @iharob I am sorry. I edited my code and question. It is the printf statements and the operations that gets executed twice.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Why not ?

Comment: You are trying to read a number. Also `atoi` requires a string. This needs a null character as well

Comment: How exactly do you intend on processing numbers that are composed of more than one character?

Comment: Perhaps reading the manual page for `scanf` might be a good start

Answer (score 3):

This

```
int n = atoi(&c);
```

is undefined behavior.

The `atoi()` function takes a `char *` pointer pointing to a string, AKA a sequence of non-`nul` bytes followed by a `nul` byte.

You are passing a pointer to a single `char`, then `atoi()` increments the pointer trying to find the terminating `'\0'` but dereferencing the incremented pointer is undefined behavior because the pointer does not point to an array.

When there is undefined behavior in your code, it doesn't matter what other behavior you observe because it might very well be caused by the *undefined behavior* problem.

To convert a single `char` to `int` you just need to subtract the ascii value of `0` from the ascii value of the digit like this

```
int n = c - '0';
```

but that doesn't guarantee that `n` is the value you expect, for that you need to check with `isdigit(c)` before attempting to use `c` as if it were a digit.

Also: The type of `c` is wrong, it should be `int` since `getchar()` returns `int` and you don't want the value to be truncated.